# loopback angular 404 on refresh page

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, loopback

I have create an application with loopback and angular but i have a problem. When i refresh the browser loopback give me a 404 url not Found.

Added base tag to index.html

```
<base href="/"/>
```

Set middlelware.json properly to serve static content:

```
"files": {
"loopback#static": {
  "params": "$!../client"
}
```

Set HTML5 mode in angular router (I'm using ui-router)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

I have yet deleted root.js from the project.

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that is because you are using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`         . try this `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`

Comment: Miqe you are a lifesaver thank you so much!!! But now when I change page, the url in browser's address bar not change. How can i solve this little problem?

Comment: Good to know, I've made my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Daigo How can this be implemented using angular 2 or angular4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have enabled html5 mode/ push state mode ON in angularjs, this is a common scenario which your server should handle. If I understood your problem correctly, server returns 404 when you refresh the page which otherwise  render fine if navigated from landing page. Let me know if this is the scenario:

- Angular app lands into Home screen, say *your_domain/*
- Navigate to some other page - *your_domain/somepage* (which will be *your_domain/#somepage* in case of hash bang mode)
- Refresh the page -> throws 404

If the scenario which you face is like given above, then this is what happens:

- Loads the home page -> angular is bootstraped and routing is set up
- Navigates to "somepage" -> angular route handles this and show "somepage"
- Refresh the page -> request hits the server and requests for *your_domain/somepage* - which is not available in server
- server returns 404

How to handle this?
Do Url rewrite back to *your_domain/* from server in case of 404. This will bootstrap the angular app and angular route will handle the request

More details here - [`https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

*Copy pasting from above website*

**Apache Rewrites**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Nginx Rewrites**

```
server {
    server_name my-app;

    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**Azure IIS Rewrites**

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**Express Rewrites**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/partials'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(3006); //the port you want to use
```

**ASP.Net C# Rewrites**

In Global.asax

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/default.aspx";

protected void Application_BeginRequest( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
    if ( !System.IO.File.Exists( Context.Server.MapPath( url ) ) )
        Context.RewritePath( ROOT_DOCUMENT );
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation for  resolve this problem. Thank you so much. It solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

This can be frustrating BUT I got you covered.
This is tested and works on Nginx Ubuntu 14/16/18.. with angular 5+

Edit /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default OR where ever you set your server settings.
This is the configuration that works:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <YOUR SERVER DOMAIN>;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root /wwweb/<location to angular dist>/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that is because you are using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` . try this `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`