# Making URL's pretty returns 404 with angular and sails to get SEO friendly url's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, sails.js

I am facing a 404 error while refreshing the page when HTML5MODE is true, in my architecture i have setup angular with sails such that when '/' is called sails throws an index.html page from where angular boots-up. but when i refresh or reload the page the it goes to 404 page of sails, i know the problem is that sails dosen't have the route defined and hence throws an 404 error. but i couldn't find a possible solution to my problem, i even tried creating a new policy but it dosen't differentiate between the API call and file as both are XHR request made by angular.

policy:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.xhr) {   
    return  res.sendfile(sails.config.appPath + '/assets/index.html');
  } 
  return next();
};
```

route:

```
'/': function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(sails.config.appPath + '/assets/index.html');
},
```

My motive behind this is to achieve SEO friendly URL's with angular and sails.

Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: not sure about sails - I have a post here, please have a look whether that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39140796/5665484

Comment: thanks for your link, but it dosen't helps, trying my own hunch, will update the post if any success.
any more suggestions are welcome.